# Why does newer versions of Bootstrap not include a background color for the btn class?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

After attempting to upgrade to a newer version of bootstrap, I noticed that all buttons with the class btn looked different.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Here is a simple JSBin illustrating what I am talking about:
https://jsbin.com/hobawuyufi/edit?html,output

Toggle between the two cdn links that I have included in this jsbin:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In the 4.1 version, the button looks like this:

[image]

In the 4.2 version, the button looks different:

[image]

I'm noticing this css property seems to be missing in the latest verion:

`background-color: buttonface;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to read the minds of the Bootstrap maintainers.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/colors/#background-color

Comment: You can post an issue on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) to get the answer directly from the maintainers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.btn` background-color was changed to transparent as of Bootstrap 4.2.0.

Here's the commit: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27002

The reasoning seems to be that there should be no "opinion" on button background color, and the modifier classes (`btn-*`) can be used to change the button color.